# How to check if a linestring intersects a polygon in Java

Tags: java, mapbox, polygon, intersection

I am trying to generate a `linestring` that avoids multiple `polygons` on a map, but in order to do this I need a method to check if a `linestring` intersects with a `polygon`. Initally I tried using this method which takes in the coordinates of the endpoint of the `linestring` and a list of the polygons to avoid:

```
public boolean Intersects(Double endPosLng, Double endPosLat, List<Polygon> polygons) {
Boolean intersects = false; 
    Point end = Point.fromLngLat(endPosLng, endPosLat);
    for (Polygon poly : polygons) {
        if (TurfJoins.inside(end, poly)) {
            intersects = true;
        }
    }
    return intersects;
}
```

But `TurfJoins.inside(end, polygon)`only considers the endpoint of the `linestring`, so the line may cut the corner of a polygon(see image below), but still end up outside the polygon so the method doesn't detect it as an intersection.

[image: Line cuts through polygon]

I thought about passing in the previous coordinates of the `linestring` to generate a section of the `linestring` but I don't think Mapbox has a method that checks if a `linestring` intersects a `polygon` at any point.

How could I check if a `linestring` intersects with a polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `Point` appears to be the wrong point class. You should be using `java.awt.Point`, not `Point` from whatever GeoJSON library you're using. Next, if your polygon doesn't have a large amount of edges, you can simply check if the line intersects any of the edges:

```java
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;

class Intersects {
    public static boolean intersects(Line2D line, Polygon poly) {
        for (int i = 0; i < poly.npoints; i ++) {
            int nextI = (i + 1) % poly.npoints;
            Line2D edge = new Line2D.Double(poly.xpoints[i], poly.ypoints[i], poly.xpoints[nextI], poly.ypoints[nextI]);
            if (line.intersectsLine(edge)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // test cases
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polygon poly = new Polygon(
                new int[]{0, 1, 1, 0},
                new int[]{0, 0, 1, 1},
                4
        ); // square of edge length 1 with bottom-left corner at (0, 0)
        Line2D[] lines = new Line2D[]{
                new Line2D.Double(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5), // true
                new Line2D.Double(0.5, 2.0, 0.5, 3.0), // false
                new Line2D.Double(0.5, -0.1, 1.2, 0.5) // true
        };
        for (Line2D line: lines) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %b\n", line, intersects(line, poly));
        }
    }
}
```